# Logo won't show on nav bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

HTML and CSS aren't really my primary thing, I'm more back-end. But I still understand it enough to make websites. I'm trying to get my logo on the left side of the nav bar, just like we see on stack overflow. But it won't show, and I just can't see why it wont. There's no erros in my console when I inspect the page on chrome.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class ="nav">      
        <ul>    
            <a href="index.html" <img src="images/logoHeader.png" alt="Backpackers Hostel" id="logo"/>  
            <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a> </li>
            <li><a href="prices.html">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="cafe.html">Cafe</a></li>
            <li><a href="gettingHere.html">Getting Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactForm.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #666666;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.nav li {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #123;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #737373;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

#logo{
    float: left;
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: navBar]

Comment: There's a typo in your anchor above

Comment: I'd make sure your directory leading to the image is correct.  You may need to add an additional backslash "/images/logoHeader.png".  Change your </nav> to </div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely the way you have the first anchor tag setup

```
<a href="index.html" <img src="images/logoHeader.png" alt="Backpackers Hostel" id="logo"/>
```

Should be

```
<li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logoHeader.png" alt="Backpackers Hostel" id="logo"/></a></li>
```

Notice how the code formatting doesn't work on the first sample. That should be a pretty good indication that something is off.

Comment: Ohh. I'm so stupid for not noticing that! I was messing around with it and must have removed it. Thanks!

Comment: And the closing `</nav>` in the end, it should be `</div>` instead

Comment: Yes also what Hamza said too!

Answer (score 1):

Your html sintax seems incorrect at that line:

```
<a href="index.html" <img src="images/logoHeader.png" alt="Backpackers Hostel" id="logo"/>
```

Try to write like this:

```
<li><a href="index.html"> <img src="images/logoHeader.png" alt="Backpackers Hostel" id="logo"/> </a></li>
```

Put everything inside `<li>`, or put the image outside the `<ul>` tag.

You also made a little mistake at the enclosing of `<div>`. The correct code should be:

```
<header>
    <div class ="nav">      
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="index.html"> <img src="images/logoHeader.png" alt="Backpackers Hostel" id="logo"/></a></li>  
            <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a> </li>
            <li><a href="prices.html">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="cafe.html">Cafe</a></li>
            <li><a href="gettingHere.html">Getting Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactForm.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Didn't notice I didn't close the div. Thanks!